# Training accuracy improves but validation and test accuracy don't

Tags: overfitting, lstm, dropout

I am training an LSTM classifier on a binary data set in order to predict if a body-headline set is related or unrelated. The headline and body were combined as a string and then the features were extracted using a BERT transformer. The training dataset is biased with related being around `10722` and unrelated about `29255`. I'm passing in the embedding and label into the model.

I tried to undersample the training dataset according to [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320232/pytorch-how-to-undersample-using-weightedrandomsampler), and it increased my training accuracy, but my validation and test accuracy remain stagnant at about 72%, maybe jumping up to 75% while my training accuracy reaches mid 80's or even 90's.

My LSTM model arch looks a little like this:

```
dropout layer
LSTM layer
dropout layer
linear layer
```

Comment: Hard to help without data, code, and context. Can you give us more information

Comment: @DemetriPananos sure! What is the best way to add the info? I'm a little new to stackexchange

Comment: You can edit your answer to give some more co text into what you’re modeling. Imagine you are talking to a grad student from a different department but has proficiency in stats and math. As for code and data, a GitHub repo is probably best.